Custom properties in the CAD model is not in metadata properties file
{urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) does not return any custom properties of the objects.
Is there anyway to retrieve all the properties including custom properties using the model derivative APIs?
I have a CAD model and I need to extract all the properties (including custom properties) of the objects inside the CAD model.

What is the input file format? What do you mean by custom properties? e..g if it's Inventor then you mean iProperties?
